# using ForceClient in Force.com Toolkit for .NET to save a pdf attachment

Tags: c#, salesforce, toolkit

My attachment is being saved in the lead but the issue is it wont open.

```
     private string GetFileAsStringBase64(Stream stream)
        {
            var data =  new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
            var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            var finalData = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
            var response = await client.CreateAsync("Attachment", new Attachment { Body = finalData , Name = _model.DirectorInformation.Attachment.FileName, ParentId = _model.LeadId });
        }
  public class Attachment
    {
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ParentId { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the string data it was not being encoded properly to base64string.
Below code will convert it into base64 string as salesforce expect.

```
            System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(stream);
            Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)stream.Length);
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return base64String;
```